# How can I scrap the ATM transaction fee of a major bank in Canada, customer for 20 years, from now on?

Tags: canada, fees, transaction, atm

I am with a major bank in Canada that charges a particular fee for visa credit card and ATM debit card money withdrawal and probably for deposit also.

I pay interest for the credit card.

I have been with this bank for over 20 years.

Now is it possible to scrap the ATM transaction fee from now on altogether?

I already told them to do just that. But they declined.

So was anyone successful in doing just that in Canada?

Comment: There are banks that offer no-fee ATM withdrawals, and some also refund other bank’s fees as well. Have you looked for another bank?

Comment: To tell you the truth I don't feel comfortable with small banks or credit unions. And all other major banks like Royal Bank, CIBC, Scotia Bank or even TD Bank charges a fee for ATM transactions. I was just wondering as I have been a customer with my current bank for so long, have a good credit score and above all good track record is there any way I can convince the customer service for canceling the fee?

Comment: I don't know why people use stand-alone ATMs. Other than the one physically located in my bank, I've never used an ATM to withdraw cash..  Many stores offer "cash back" when you make a payment with a debit card.  Next time you buy something, ask for $100 cash back and they'll add it to the purchase cost and give you the money in change, with no additional service charge.

Comment: @Ray Sometimes you need cash and don't want to make a purchase just to get cash back. Or need cash in excess of the cash back limit. Or have an ATM only card (are these still available?) What I don't understand is going all the way to your bank just to use the ATM.

Comment: @mvr950: Tangerine is owned by Scotiabank. Simplii is owned by CIBC. Both institutions offer CDIC protection. Are you uncomfortable banking with a subsidiary of Scotiabank or CIBC? If so, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most Canadian banks have an account type that allows you to make unlimited free ATM withdrawals and they don’t charge you an annual fee e.g. CIBC smart account. The catch is that you have to maintain a certain minimum balance in your account (in the case of CIBC it’s 3K). If you can maintain that type of balance then all you need to do is switch to the no-fee account. If you can’t then you’re best off to switching to a credit union, or a bank like Tangerine where they frequently don’t charge ATM fees (but only on their machines).